# Pull on insert the auto increment id

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm using a SQL Server (`.MDF`) database with C# and I want pull on insert the auto increment id.

Currently I have a table with 3 cells:

1. Id || int
2. StartDate || datetime
3. GameMode || nchar(10)

On code level I'm not inserting the ID cell, the setup of the database takes care of it:

```
db.TblGames.InsertOnSubmit(new TblGame { StartDate = DateTime.Now, GameMode = gm.ToString() });
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you're using LINQ to SQL. The auto-generated id should be in the TblGame instance after `.SubmitChanges()` returns. Keep the TblGame instance to retrieve it, like this:

```
var game = new TblGame { StartDate = DateTime.Now, GameMode = gm.ToString() };
db.TblGames.InsertOnSubmit(game);
db.SubmitChanges();
var id = game.Id;
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not working, 
after new TblGame command the game.Id = 0. therefore it will cause an error on submitChanges.

Comment: Are you sure that the Id column is marked as "Auto Generated" in the LINQ to SQL designer then?